# In Mercurial, is it possible to display the diff between 2 revisions in the web view?

Tags: mercurial

From the command line, the command would be run like this:

```
hg diff -r250 -r260 path/to/myfile.py
```

Is it possible to get a view like that in the web view? A diff view like [this](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-c/diff/42b43818025f/tests/test_tables.c), but for two non-successive revisions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't currently possible (as of Mercurial 2.3).

Mercurial version 2.3 introduced a side-by-side comparison view, but it only shows the differences introduced by each changeset (i.e. between a revision and its parent).

I recommend using a third-part, GUI-based diff tool, and enabling and configuring Mercurial's [extdiff](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ExtdiffExtension) extension to use it.  You can then run your diff command through extdiff:

```
hg extdiff -r250 -r260 path/to/myfile.py
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's just the difference between a revision and its parent. You can see an example here: http://selenic.com/hg/comparison/b32a30da608d/mercurial/verify.py

Comment: Great, I've reversed my vote to a +1! The part about extdiff is good, I hadn't thought of that myself :)